# Can we have table without primary key in entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I was just practicing code first new database entity framework from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542), I wanna know whether a table without primary key can be created in code first new database EF?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944366/how-do-you-update-a-table-with-a-foreign-key-to-another-table-in-ado-net-entity

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068920/code-first-ctp4-table-with-no-primary-key

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No you can't because Entity Framework needs to know the key to keep track on the object when you make an update or delete operation.

**Anyway it's not a good idea to have a table without a PrimaryKey**

Comment: Ok wahid, you are right, a table without PK, general operation like update or delete can't be performed, but if i can tell EF to use a particular column which is unique but not PK, then in that case , this operation(update, delete) can be performed by EF?

Comment: No the column should be PK

Comment: SHOULD <> MUST. As long as you don't rely on code first I'm pretty sure you can use any unique column as the key and EF won't see a thing. However, you might have performance issues (unless your other column is the clustered index, but in that case why not make it the primary key).

Comment: According to SQL Server docs, no-key tables (heaps) should be used when there is no much data for imporoved lookup.

Comment: Does Lookup table also need primary key? I just want to retrieve the data from that tables. I don't want to do the add, update & delete operations.

Comment: Agree. I've noticed that EF 4.0 (and higher) enable user to have a table without primary key, but that table have to contain at least one foreign key. Then, it's possible to set up model builder. For those, who want to know how to achieve that, please follow this link: [Entity Framework: table without primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996782/entity-framework-table-without-primary-key)

Comment: @WahidBitar what if I have just composite key and not any other key in table ?

Comment: @MoxShah I didn't understand your question clearly, but you can have multiple fields marked as a compound key

Comment: @WahidBitar in some of my tables, we were having multiple primary key (which is Composite Key), but somehow EF doesn't understand that and whenever we try to make any DB transaction, it was throwing an error saying particular table doesn't have any primary key.

Later we changed those tables and added single field as primary key.

Comment: @MoxShah Yes, I guess you'll have this in EF core. Sadly I don't know why in some cases it doesn't accept table with just composed key. As I tried if the table is part of many to many relationships it will work, but when you have a table without this relationship it will not work till you add a standalone primary key.

Comment: @WahidBitar Thanks for your response Wahid, appreciate it, for now I have added standalone primary key.

Comment: Anyway it's not a good idea to say "it's not a good idea to have a table without a PrimaryKey".

Answer (score 51):

There is a great difference between what EF can do with a database, and what is possible with a database.

**Most databases allow for a table to be without a primary key.** Most databases also allow for a table to be without a clustered index / Index Organized Table (or what ever it is the specific term for it in other database systems).

There is nothing wrong with that, and one should not state that it is a bad idea to have a table without a PK.

As always, it dependes on the needs and usage of the specific table. e.g. a log table, does not need a PK. It will never be used as a FK, so what is it use?

Bottom line, **EF does not support tables without a key** out of the box, there are some weird workarounds, but none that I have seen is good enough. That is a shame.

Comment: Exactly. We have a settings table with one record. Doesn't really need a PK.

Comment: I have a program that is not made by another company and that I thus cannot alter, but it has a table without primary key, it contains order rows for well, orders. Individual rows are updated or deleted by using two columns such as the articleID (or perhaps row number) and orderID combined, adding new rows is no problem. This is one way it seems to be used. Not saying it's a good or bad idea, just a real life example and something I have to deal with if I want to interface to the same database with EF.

Comment: "one should not state that it is a bad idea to have a table without a PK". That is really a great idea to create tables without PKs. I think it should be default option when creating tables, who needs PK if not for FKs, right, right?

Answer (score 17):

1. Entity Framework **must** have a key identified on the entity (POCO class) that models the table.
2. The key you define in Entity Framework does **NOT** need to be present in the underlying database (e.g. sql table).

If your SQL table does not have a primary key, you can still model it in Entity Framework, you will just need to define a key for that Entity.  Pick one or more (possibly all) columns on the Entity that, when combined, will uniquely identify that instance within a collection of the entities.  Note this is only important for updating or deleting entities, in that they need to be uniquely identified against the others in that collection to target the change.  Find/Select and Add/Insert do not require this consistency.

Comment: but it is not letting me add the table at all

Comment: @dangalg Yes, Entity Framework can infer a key, and it will work for select. But if you need to insert, update or delete data, then you need a primary key in database.

Answer (score 13):

Sometimes adding PK is not possible because it can be read-only, super protected database of a client which you have to use.
EF throws exception even on SELECT operations. When I faced that issue I was able to solve it like this (names are artificial):

```
[Table( "WeirdTable", Schema = "SomeSchema" )]
public class WeirdTable
{
    [Column( "ID1" )]
    public int Id1 { get; set; }

    [Column( "ID2" )]
    public int Id2 { get; set; }
}
```

In the code file of context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder model_builder )
{
    base.OnModelCreating( model_builder );
    model_builder.Entity<WeirdTable>().HasKey(
        t => new { t.Id1, t.Id2 }
    );
}
```

So basically you just need to specify which columns can be primary key.

Answer (score 11):

Starting with .NET Core 2.1, EF Core supports models without primary key.
This is realized through a concept of *Query Types* instead of *Enitity Types*.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types

> Some of the main usage scenarios for query types are:
>
> - Serving as the return type for ad hoc FromSql() queries.
> - Mapping to database views.
> - **Mapping to tables that do not have a primary key defined.**
> - Mapping to queries defined in the model.

*Query Types* have limits though. They cannot be inserted, updated or deleted on the database. And they have only limited support of navigation properties.

Comment: so, I have a question. when we Map a Query type to a table. the table treats as read-only and we can't CRUD on it, well how can we fil that table with data?? at first-time run application how to must we fill that table?!!

Answer (score 3):

EF.Core 5 will have `[Keyless]` attribute allowing to have an entity without PK.
But it is still under development.

[EF.Core 5 what's new](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew)

Comment: Documentation page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types

Comment: Would be nice if you could update this answer (and maybe show an example).