# EF Add table from Database without PK

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

trying to add a table without a PK, EF throws this warning:

> Error 6013: The table/view does not have a primary key
>   defined and no valid primary key could be inferred. This table/view
>   has been excluded. To use the entity, you will need to review your
>   schema, add the correct keys, and uncomment it.

I cant change anything in the database, since i only have a reading user to read data from it.

Is there a way to add the table to the context, even there is no PK?

Thanks

Comment: You might have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381233/can-we-have-table-without-primary-key-in-entity-framework)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we have table without primary key in entity framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381233/can-we-have-table-without-primary-key-in-entity-framework)