# getting same row in entityframework for table without primary key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, primary-key

I have below data in database table "City" with no primary key

```
CityId  CityName
1       ABC
1       XYZ
```

I am using entityframework to fetch this data and I am getting same row.
Below is the Context Class code

```
public class StudentsDbContext :DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<City> cities { get; set; }
    }
```

Below is the City Class Code

```
[Table("City")]
    public class City
    {
        [Key]
        public int CityId { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }
    }
```

Below is the output code

```
StudentsDbContext studentsDbContext = new StudentsDbContext();
            List<City> cities = studentsDbContext.cities.ToList();
            foreach (var val in cities)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("studentName: " + val.CityName);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Below is the output image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGc3y.png)

Below is the desired result

```
CityName: ABC
CityName: XYZ
```

Comment: What have you tried? what doesn't work?

Comment: You also need to use `DefaultIfEmpty` if you want to do a left join.

Comment: Use Left Outer Join : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause

Comment: I have updated my issue that I have found please help me with this

Comment: I'm glad you edited the post, but currently you don't have any questions in the new post. Before the post was edited you mentioned a left outer join. Are you still willing to do that? If yes I can help.

Comment: @RichárdBaldauf I was not able to get desired result because of this above problem

Comment: what is the desired result?

Comment: @RichárdBaldauf I have updated desired result in above post

Comment: could you try removing the `[Key]` attribute from `City` class `CityId` property?

Comment: Btw, It's not a good idea to get rid of the primary key, see answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381233/can-we-have-table-without-primary-key-in-entity-framework

Comment: @RichárdBaldauf but if there is such a case then do you know how can we do it in EF

Comment: @shin95 Gotcha! The CityId is the same for both city, if you going to chane the Id for the second city (XYZ) it shoud work.

Comment: @RichárdBaldauf I dont want to change the data...I need both rows with same exact values